# middleware только для одно контроллера

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core

Я создал свой middleware

```html
    public class RequestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IRequestService _service;

        public RequestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IRequestService service)
        {
            _next = next;
            _service = service;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
           

            var newModel = new RequestModel()
            {
                IpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                Referer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"]
            };

            if (newModel.Referer != null)
                _service.AddRequest(newModel);

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Как сделать что бы он выполнялся только при запросах к контроллеру `ProductsController` ?

Answer (score 0):

В методе `Configure` класса `Startup` добавил  `app.Map("/products",a => a.UseRequest());`